# Question on solution of matchbox problem

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, conditional-probability, negative-binomial

> Suppose a mathematician carries two matchboxes at all times: one in his left pocket and one in his right. Each time he needs a match, he is equally likely to take it from either pocket. Suppose he reaches into his pocket and discovers for the first time that the box picked is empty. If it is assumed that each of the matchboxes originally contained $N$ matches, what is the probability that there are exactly $k$ matches in the other box? (see, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach%27s_matchbox_problem)

The solution on wikipedia includes the following equation:

[image]

---

Why does $2\cdot P(M=N-k)={2N-k\choose N-k}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{2N-k}$ hold?

**My idea:**

If we forget for a moment the matchbox problem and simply consider *a* negative binomial distribution $P_{nb}$ where we have $N+1$ successes and ask for the probability of $m$-many failures, then we can define *a* conditional probability $P_{nb}(M=m\mid m<N+1)$. If we replace $m$ by $N-k$ then this conditional probability describes the matchbox problem. In other words
\begin{align*}
&\underset{\text{of matchbox problem}}{\underset{\text{probability distribution }}{\underbrace{P(K=k)}}}=\dots=P_{nb}(M=m\mid m<N+1)\\
&=\frac{P_{nb}(M=m~\cap ~m<N+1)}{P_{nb}(m<N+1)}=\frac{{m+N\choose m}\frac{1}{2^{m+N+1}}}{P_{nb}(m<N+1)}.
\end{align*}
Now a problem remains: How do we get $P_{nb}(m<N+1)$ without further information?

Comment: Formula for $P(M=m)$ is got and written in the previous paragraph of the wikipedia article

Comment: @IvanKaznacheyeu, when reading the wikipedia article you must distinguish between two $P$'s! The one in the previous paragraph and the one in the above equation that refers to the original matchbox problem. Unfortunately the wikipedia article doesn't make this explicit.

Comment: The meaning of previous paragraph is that its result is used for the original matchbox problem. $P(K=..)$ is for original matchbox problem, $P(M=..)$ is for infinite matchbox problem.

Comment: @IvanKaznacheyeu, yes that's clear. But I don't understand how this helps to answer my question.

Comment: If your question is "Why does $2\cdot P(M=N-k)={2N-k\choose N-k}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{2N-k}$ hold?" my comment answers your question. If your question is "Why does $P(M=N-k|M<N+1)=2P(M=N-k)$ hold?", it doesn't.

Comment: @IvanKaznacheyeu, I think I made clear what my question is. No, your comment doesn't answer my question. Please notice that there are two different probability functions, one lives in the probability space of the matchbox experiment and the other one lives in the probability space of the negative binomial exeriment. If you take this into your consideration it's not clear why the equation should hold.